# Google CNAME for .xyz domain

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-search-console

I am trying to get my .xyz site (`igoogle.ipet.xyz to be CNAME to c.storage.googleapis.com`)

In WHM I have added `igoogle CNAME c.storage.googleapis.com` to the site.xyz domain however it seems that google only is allowing .com domains or top level domains.

So I am wondering if anyone has been able to get this to work with .xyz or any newer domains

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't the .xyz domain. GCS buckets may not have the word "google" or close misspellings in their name. See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming#requirements